# Is there a way to avoid writing ==, eql? and hash methods in Ruby (template class?)

Tags: ruby, hash, equals

When writing big classes with loads of instance variables, writing ==, eql? and hash methods is a big hassle. Is there a way to make a "template class" to automate this process? Or with any other ways.

Example:

```
class Template
    def ==(other)
      //Some way of comparing all of self's instance variables to other's.
    end

    def eql?(other)
      self == other
    end

    def hash
      //Some way of XORing the instance variables of self
    end
end

class Test < Example
    attr_reader :foo
    attr_reader :bar

    def initialize(foo, bar)
      @foo = foo
      @bar = bar
    end
end

a = Test.new "123", "456"
b = Test.new "123", "456"
a == b
> true
```

Comment: There is no need to define that version of `eql?` as that is the default defined for all Objects. Your `==` can be defined generally using metaprogramming as in Tero's answer. You can define a "template class" by putting your methods in a module and including it.

Comment: That's actually incorrect: `Object#eql?` is object-identity equality (just like `#equal?`). The docs are poorly worded; they say, “For objects of class `Object`, `eql?` is synonymous with `==`.” That's only because `Object#==` is also object-identity equality. If you override `#==` and want your `#eql?` to respect your new logic, you have to override `#eql?` as well. The docs go on to say, “Subclasses normally continue this tradition by aliasing `eql?` to their overridden `==` method”. Notably, though, you can use `alias eql? ==`, which is a bit shorter.

Answer (score 2):

```
Test = Struct.new(:foo, :bar)

a = Test.new "123", "456"
b = Test.new "123", "456"

a == b
# => true
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define your fields so that you are able to reflect on them later on.  Assuming all instance variables always exist and you want to use all of them in similar fashion, Ruby already provides you with enough reflection to pull it off, about this way

```
class MyFineClass
  attr_reader :foo, :bar # and loads of stuff

  def initialize(...)
    # tons of those ivars initialized
  end

  def ==(other)
    other.is_a?(self.class) &&
      # this assumes all instance variables to have attr_readers
      instance_variables.all? { |ivar| send(ivar) == other.send(ivar) }
      # ...and if they don't, you need instance_variable_get, like this
      #instance_variables.all? { |ivar| instance_variable_get(ivar) == other.instance_variable_get(ivar) }
  end
end
```

In case you want more control over how the fields should be treated, you could add a notion of "field" and a little metaprogramming

```
class MyFineClass
  @fields = []
  def self.fields; @fields; end

  def self.fields(field_name)
    attr_reader field_name
    @fields << field_name
  end

  field :foo
  field :bar
  # and loads more

  def initialize(...)
    # again, tons of those ivars initialized
  end

  def ==(other)
    other.is_a?(self.class) && self.class.fields.all? { |f| send(f) == other.send(f) }
  end
end
```

Next you would of course pull `fields` stuff and `==` to separate module and include that to `MyFineClass`.  Got the idea?  Develop that module a little further and it might start looking a little like certain bits in `ActiveModel` or `DataMapper`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Ruby Facets](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets) provides the [Equitable](http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/f/facets-2.9.3/Equitable.html) module, which provides almost exactly what you're looking for.

Your example would become:

```
class Test
  include Equitable(:foo, :bar)
end
```

If you don't want to use the whole gem, you can grab [the source](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/master/lib/standard/facets/equitable.rb) - it's pretty light.